# Cannot dump or return relation array inside mongoose object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to learn basic relations with MongoDB and mongoose using Node and Express.

**User Model**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

userSchema.virtual("posts", {
    ref: "Post",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "userId"
});

// Making sure that password field is not present in responses
userSchema.methods.toJSON = function() {
    let user = this.toObject();
    delete user.password;

    // console.log(user.posts);

    return user;
};

// Creating model from schema
User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

**Post Model**

```
let mongoose = require("mongoose");

postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    body: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "User"
    }
});

let Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

These are the two models I am working with. Users have many posts.

Now I know I can get one user by:

`let user = await User.findOne();`

And I can populate the posts relation by:

`await user.populate("posts").execPopulate();`

But when I `console.log(user)` or `res.send(user)`, I only see the user data, I don't see the posts relation data. I can `console.log(user.posts)` and get the data that way. But why won't it come with the object itself? Is this default behaviour and if it is, how do I get the user object with the posts array in my response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use virtual populate you need to add `toJSON: { virtuals: true }` option to the schema.

So it should be like this:

```js
userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  }
);
```

From the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals):

> Keep in mind that virtuals are not included in toJSON() output by
>   default. If you want populate virtuals to show up when using functions
>   that rely on JSON.stringify(), like Express' res.json() function, set
>   the virtuals: true option on your schema's toJSON options.